# Routing on SG300 with VLANs

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-sg300

My setup:

I receive from my ISP a `/24` public IP subnet (e.g: `20.20.20.0/24`).

Some of our departments want to have full control over their public IPs, so I split it up to several `/27` subnets.

For the beginning I wanted to set up 3 VLANs:

1. VLAN 100: `20.20.20.32/27`
2. VLAN 200: `20.20.20.128/27`
3. VLAN 5 (WAN connect): `20.20.20.0/30`

The Gateway of the switch is `20.20.20.1`.

I configured a static route on the SG300-28 (is in L3 mode):

`0.0.0.0/0` over `20.20.20.1`

Clients in the VLAN 100 or the VLAN 200 can't reach the ISP Gateway or the internet.

If I put the client in the VLAN 5 he can of course connect to the GW and the internet.

I am to blind to see the mistake, so I count on you guys.

**Cisco Packet Tracer Example: [PKT File](http://files.fuerst.it/sg300.pkt)**

Config:

```
config-file-header
switche5bce7
v1.4.5.02 / R800_NIK_1_4_194_194
CLI v1.0
set system mode router 

file SSD indicator encrypted
@
ssd-control-start 
ssd config 
ssd file passphrase control unrestricted 
no ssd file integrity control 
ssd-control-end cb0a3fdb1f3a1af4e4430033719968c0 
!
vlan database
vlan 5,10,100,200 
exit
voice vlan oui-table add 0001e3 Siemens_AG_phone________
voice vlan oui-table add 00036b Cisco_phone_____________
voice vlan oui-table add 00096e Avaya___________________
voice vlan oui-table add 000fe2 H3C_Aolynk______________
voice vlan oui-table add 0060b9 Philips_and_NEC_AG_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00d01e Pingtel_phone___________
voice vlan oui-table add 00e075 Polycom/Veritel_phone___
voice vlan oui-table add 00e0bb 3Com_phone______________
ip dhcp server 
ip dhcp pool network Pool_5
address low 20.20.20.6 high 20.20.20.10 255.255.255.224 
default-router 20.20.20.5
dns-server 8.8.8.8
exit
ip dhcp pool network Pool_100
address low 20.20.20.34 high 20.20.20.62 255.255.255.224 
default-router 20.20.20.33
dns-server 8.8.8.8
exit
ip dhcp pool network Pool_200
address low 20.20.20.130 high 20.20.20.158 255.255.255.224 
default-router 20.20.20.129
dns-server 8.8.8.8
exit
bonjour interface range vlan 1
ip access-list extended VLAN_100-IN
permit ip any any ace-priority 1
exit
ip access-list extended VLAN_1-IN
permit ip any any ace-priority 1
exit
hostname switche5bce7
line console
no autobaud
exit
no passwords complexity enable 
username cisco password encrypted d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997 privilege 15 
ip ssh server
ip ssh-client server authentication 
ip telnet server
!
interface vlan 1
 no ip address dhcp 
 service-acl input VLAN_1-IN default-action permit-any 
!
interface vlan 5
 name WAN 
!
interface vlan 10
 name MGMT 
 ip address 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0 
!
interface vlan 100
 name VLAN_100 
 ip address 20.20.20.33 255.255.255.224 
 service-acl input VLAN_100-IN default-action permit-any 
!
interface vlan 200
 name VLAN_200 
 ip address 20.20.20.129 255.255.255.224 
!
interface gigabitethernet1
 ip address 20.20.20.2 255.255.255.252 
!
interface gigabitethernet2
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 5 
!
interface gigabitethernet3
 switchport mode access 
!
interface gigabitethernet4
 switchport mode access 
!
interface gigabitethernet5
 switchport mode access 
!
interface gigabitethernet10
 service-acl input VLAN_100-IN 
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 100 
!
interface gigabitethernet20
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 200 
!
interface gigabitethernet25
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 10 
!
interface gigabitethernet26
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 10 
!
exit
ip default-gateway 20.20.20.1
```

Comment: You need to enable routing on the switch.

Comment: I forgot to write that the switch is already in L3 mode.

Comment: Did you follow the requirements? "_If Router system mode is selected, a single IP address is supported on the default VLAN. The user also must configure a default gateway._"

Comment: You should edit your question to include the full, sanitized configuration. We cannot play 20 questions.

Comment: ok I add the SW config.

Comment: are you able to ping the ISP from this switch?

Comment: yes I am able to ping from the switch (ISPs Router or 8.8.8.8).

Comment: Have you verified that the DHCP clients are getting the config that you expect?

Comment: yes, dhcp works as it should

Comment: Can you try and create a point to point link between a PC and router and see if that goes through? If it doesn't then I would guess the switch is broken.

Comment: Yes, directly attached is not a problem. I add a Cisco Packet Tracer File. It is almost like in reality, so everybody can try tell me what I made wrong.

Comment: I don't see the point in VLAN 5, and I don't follow the VLAN 10. You should set up a loopback with the VLAN 10 address for switch management, and not use a separate VLAN. You can then see if a host on one of your other VLANs can access the switch with the loopback address.

Comment: I don't believe you have enabled routing. I don't see the command to do that anywhere in your configuration.

Comment: VLAN5 was for testing. Sorry I forgot to remove it.
In the top of the config its written "set system mode router"

Have you seen the Packet Tracer file?

Comment: Hmm I just found out that my Packet Tracer example exactly do what it should. Difference is the emulated switch from the software is a enterprise multilayer switch which support routed ports with the "no switchport" command, the SG300 doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because of a limitation of the SG300. 
The SG300 doesn't have routed ports.

I set up a clean SG300 config but it was not possible to reach the ISP Gateway: 
Config of SG300:

```
config-file-header
switche5bce7
v1.4.5.02 / R800_NIK_1_4_194_194
CLI v1.0
set system mode router 

file SSD indicator encrypted
@
ssd-control-start 
ssd config 
ssd file passphrase control unrestricted 
no ssd file integrity control 
ssd-control-end cb0a3fdb1f3a1af4e4430033719968c0 
!
vlan database
vlan 100,200 
exit
voice vlan oui-table add 0001e3 Siemens_AG_phone________
voice vlan oui-table add 00036b Cisco_phone_____________
voice vlan oui-table add 00096e Avaya___________________
voice vlan oui-table add 000fe2 H3C_Aolynk______________
voice vlan oui-table add 0060b9 Philips_and_NEC_AG_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00d01e Pingtel_phone___________
voice vlan oui-table add 00e075 Polycom/Veritel_phone___
voice vlan oui-table add 00e0bb 3Com_phone______________
bonjour interface range vlan 1
hostname switche5bce7
no passwords complexity enable 
username cisco password encrypted d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997 privilege 15 
!
interface vlan 100
 name "VLAN100" 
 ip address 20.20.20.33 255.255.255.224 
!
interface vlan 200
 name "VLAN200" 
 ip address 20.20.20.129 255.255.255.224 
!
interface gigabitethernet1
 ip address 20.20.20.2 255.255.255.252 
!
interface gigabitethernet10
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 100 
!
interface gigabitethernet20
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 200 
!
exit
ip default-gateway 20.20.20.1
```

Afterwards I set up a Catalyst 3750 Switch with the same VLANs and config and I was able to issue `no switchport` on `Interface Gigabit1/0/1`. 

Now I can reach the ISP Gateway how it should be. 
Config of 3750:

```
Current configuration : 3535 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
switch 1 provision ws-c3750x-24p
system mtu routing 1500
ip routing
!
!
!         
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-2617031040
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-2617031040
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-2617031040
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
!
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache cef
 no ip route-cache
 no ip mroute-cache
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 no switchport
 ip address 20.20.20.2 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!         
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan100
 ip address 20.20.20.33 255.255.255.224
!         
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 20.20.20.1
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
ip sla enable reaction-alerts
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
end
```

Comment: On the 3750, you have a default route, but you didn't put a default route on the SG300. Without a default route, you will never reach the Internet from VLAN 100 or 200.

Comment: Also, according to the SG300 CLI manual for version 1.4, you can put an IP address on an ethernet interface. It doesn't have the `no switchport` command, but that is OK.  "_Use the **ip address** Interface Configuration (Ethernet, VLAN, Port-channel) mode
command to define an IP address for an interface. Use the **no** form of this command to remove an IP address definition._" Notice that it includes "**_ethernet**_."

Comment: Please take a look at my SG300 configI posted above: I configured an ip address for the interface gi 1 either there is a default GW defined. You can find it in the last line of the config.

Comment: You **_need_** a default route, just like you have on the 3750. That lets the other VLANs route out to the Internet. A default gateway is used for the switch, but not the layer-3 router, part of the switch.

Comment: Port GE1 has a configured ethernet IP address. If I add a default route: IP Configuration -> IPv4 Routes. With: Destination IP Prefix: 0.0.0.0 Prefix length:0 Route Type: remote Next Hop: 20.20.20.1 than it is written inside the config file with **ip default-gateway 20.20.20.1** Just to clearify: I use firmware Version: 1.4.5.02

Comment: A default gateway is very different than a default route. A default gateway is for the switch itself, not the traffic coming into the switch.

Comment: But I can't add something else. Do you have a SG300? Try it on your and you will see that it looks like this.

Comment: You have 1.4, and that has the` ip route` command. You can also do the `show ip route` command to see. "_To establish static routes, use the **ip route** command in global configuration mode. To remove static routes, use the **no** form of this command. _" and "**ip route** prefix {_mask_ | _/prefix-length_} {{_ip-address_ [**metric** _value_]}}"

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems:

- VLAN 5 isn't needed.
- VLAN 10 should be handled with a loopback.
- VLAN 100 is referencing an ACL which doesn't exist.
- There is no default route for the VLANs.

Try adding this configuration into your switch:

```
no interface vlan 5
!
no interface vlan 10
!
vlan database
 no vlan 5
 no vlan 10
exit
!
no ip dhcp pool network Pool_5
!
interface loopback 1
 name MGMT 
 ip address 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0 
!
interface vlan 100
 no service-acl input VLAN_100-IN default-action permit-any 
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 20.20.20.1
!
```